# Http process hang at PHP's Imagick's setFont(or any font operation) in macOS 10.12

Tags: php, apache, dtrace

I've asked for this problem [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467038/php-imagicks-setfont-method-take-too-long-time-to-execute).

I open this questions because I found another thing I don't know how to do.

I've checked the problem using DTrace, and I found when I try to access the PHP, the system will go into infinite loop of this:

```
select(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF4FDDCB70)               = 0 0
wait4(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFF4FDDCB54, 0x3)           = 0 0
select(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7FFF4FDDCB70)               = 0 0
wait4(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFF4FDDCB54, 0x3)           = 0 0
```

Seems, it is trying to open some file, but kept waiting for it.

The PHP code is pretty simple:

```
<?php echo count(Imagick::queryFonts());
```

What should I do for now? I've checked the opened files they are like this:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD    TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
httpd   37639 root  cwd     DIR                1,4      1462         2 /
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    407868 357831135 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    439776 359328665 /opt/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    129020 338745171 /opt/local/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9428 357829904 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9424 357829902 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    987924 338659937 /opt/local/lib/db46/libdb-4.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    130028 355436275 /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9120 357829900 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authn_anon.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1057000 359860447 /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    159012 338745074 /opt/local/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14036 357829901 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9032 357829903 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authn_default.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9664 357829899 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authn_alias.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13956 357829908 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14568 357829907 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9120 357829910 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13984 357829905 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9360 357829909 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authz_owner.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      8896 357829906 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13956 357829897 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     24620 357829898 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_auth_digest.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     15068 357829925 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_file_cache.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     36252 357829912 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_cache.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     24840 357829920 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_disk_cache.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     26776 357829935 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_mem_cache.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     19812 357829917 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_dbd.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13916 357829921 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_dumpio.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14504 357829946 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     21764 357829924 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_ext_filter.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     42796 357829930 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_include.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     18824 357829926 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_filter.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14752 357829952 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_substitute.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     28824 357829918 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     80924 357826839 /opt/local/lib/libz.1.2.11.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     27332 357829932 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_log_config.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14256 357829933 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_log_forensic.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9988 357829934 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_logio.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9376 357829922 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_env.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     24040 357829937 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_mime_magic.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14208 357829913 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_cern_meta.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14392 357829923 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     20752 357829927 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13980 357829928 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_ident.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14536 357829955 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_usertrack.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13924 357829953 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_unique_id.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14412 357829948 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13364 357829956 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_version.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     73816 357829939 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14040 357829942 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     35416 357829943 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     36100 357829944 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     16476 357829945 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     34988 357829940 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     29480 357829941 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    172352 357829950 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    405728 359056150 /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   2066240 359056147 /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     19560 357829936 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     82224 357829915 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_dav.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     23472 357829951 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_status.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     34408 357829911 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9328 357829896 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_asis.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     20484 357829931 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_info.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     27580 357829914 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     46604 357829916 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_dav_fs.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13812 357829957 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     34360 357829938 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13876 357829919 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     18576 357829929 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_imagemap.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4      9544 357829894 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_actions.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14408 357829949 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_speling.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     13768 357829954 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_userdir.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14612 357829895 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     60220 357829947 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   7767324 363852380 /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_php70.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     86384 355443983 /opt/local/lib/libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1185852 355443860 /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    138332 355807972 /opt/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    150888 363852810 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/opcache.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     82972 363852434 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/curl.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    387940 362694902 /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    344180 363852487 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/gd.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     14316 355447988 /opt/local/lib/libXau.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     15148 359412965 /opt/local/lib/libcom_err.1.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1688784 331297873 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/clips.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    176948 357833609 /opt/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    207280 355473744 /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    375368 360003315 /opt/local/lib/libwebp.7.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    600020 355807781 /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     40588 363852586 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/iconv.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    329340 359332579 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/imagick.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1290088 362735327 /opt/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.4.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   2263816 362735323 /opt/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.4.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    300176 355476049 /opt/local/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1022420 355476417 /opt/local/lib/libfftw3.3.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    246928 355447385 /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     63460 355464063 /opt/local/lib/libXext.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    328232 355477069 /opt/local/lib/libXt.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     35780 355445162 /opt/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     34360 359304584 /opt/local/lib/libSM.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     84496 355476098 /opt/local/lib/libICE.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1133072 355463775 /opt/local/lib/libX11.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    142196 355462508 /opt/local/lib/libxcb.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     23460 355447932 /opt/local/lib/libXdmcp.6.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4   1340628 363852649 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mbstring.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    111088 363852733 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mysqli.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     26308 363852734 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/pdo_mysql.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    137024 363852867 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/openssl.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    247056 362709877 /opt/local/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    745108 362709900 /opt/local/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     90356 362709883 /opt/local/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     42020 362709903 /opt/local/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4     50156 355442874 /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    111952 363852919 /opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/zip.so
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4    697712 365015204 /usr/lib/dyld
httpd   37639 root  txt     REG                1,4 673185792 365076146 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
httpd   37639 root    0r    CHR                3,2       0t0       305 /dev/null
httpd   37639 root    1w    CHR                3,2       0t0       305 /dev/null
httpd   37639 root    2w    REG                1,4   5286028 200044953 /opt/local/apache2/logs/error_log
httpd   37639 root    3r    CHR                3,2       0t0       305 /dev/null
httpd   37639 root    4u  systm                          0t0           
httpd   37639 root    5u   IPv6 0x4caef1335c227d7d       0t0       TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   37639 root    6u   IPv4 0x4caef13355c41c85       0t0       TCP *:* (CLOSED)
httpd   37639 root    7u   unix 0x4caef13361a9b03d       0t0           ->0x4caef133493fa99d
httpd   37639 root    8u   unix 0x4caef13361a9b105       0t0           ->0x4caef13361a9cc5d
httpd   37639 root    9    PIPE 0x4caef133511a83dd     16384           ->0x4caef133511a675d
httpd   37639 root   10    PIPE 0x4caef133511a675d     16384           ->0x4caef133511a83dd
httpd   37639 root   11w    REG                1,4  51704973    842973 /opt/local/apache2/logs/access_log
httpd   37639 root   12u    REG                1,4         0 365092611 /private/tmp/.ZendSem.IBeoef
```

What should I do from now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select and wait4 seems to be normal for Apache. Just showing the socket listening is working, has nothing to do with my question, so need to close this question for now.